# Change color of cells based on value in DB

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to accomplish the following.

I have a "grid" in which each cell can be 'owned' by a user.

To 'own' some new cells, the user should be able to click on two points (in a straight line) on the grid and then confirm by clicking on a button or cancel by clicking on another button, which updates the state of the grid. *When both points are clicked, the cells between the two clicked ones must change color.*

I should mention that I would like to achieve this only by using plain Javascript / PHP, if possible.

**What I've done so far**:

- I have stored the 'grid' in a DB, having a record for each cell, containing position (i, j), owner and some other feature.
- I query the DB using PHP, I save everything in memory (2D array - the grid is supposed to be small) and represent the grid by generating an HTML table
- I'm trying to use JS to change the color of the cells when clicking, but I'm having problems (I'm new to JS and web programming in general).

I'm sure there's some kind of pattern to do what I want to do (surely is not rocket science), and would completely agree the following is pure Spaghetti code, but that's the only way I thought of doing it given my very very limited experience.

I do the following.
I have an HTML page with a named div in which I represent the table

```
<div id="Vis_table"> <?php echo $table ?> </div>
```

At the end of the `body` I have a script, which I report in its essential elements

```
var click = 0;
var grid = <?php echo json_encode($grid); ?>;
var Y_grid = <?php echo Y_g; ?>;


if (click == 0) { //first click
    var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("th"); //take all cells
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { // all rows
        var row = parseInt(i / (Y_grid)); //dimensions
        var col = i % (Y_grid);

        cells[i].onclick = (function (xr, yc, index) {
            return function () {
                if (click == 0) { //first click, start
                    var tab = "<table>";
                    for (var x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
                        tab += "<tr>";
                        for (var y = 0; y < grid[0].length; y++) {
                            if (x == xr && y == yc) { //if it's the cell i clicked on
                                tab += "<th class = 'clicked'>" + x + " " + y + "</th>";
                            } else {
                                tab += "<th class = 'free'> </th>";
                            }
                        }
                        tab += "</tr>";
                    }
                    tab += "</table>";
                    click = 1;
                    document.getElementById("Vis_table").innerHTML = tab;
                }
            };
        })(row, col, i);
    }
}
```

Now, this works just fine, and the clicked cell changes color according to the CSS rules. The problem is that I don't know how to go on (ie color the cells between the first and the second clicked cells).

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table prepared via JS(to do this in PHP is your task).

Area marking in JS :)

I've split the task in small steps to its easier to understand. If you got questions, feel free to ask!

```js
/* This is generated by PHP (for testing i do it with js here) >>> */
var rows = 5;
var cols = 10;
var $table = $('#myTable');

for( let row = 1; row <= rows; row++ ) {
  $row = $('<tr>');
  
  for( let col = 1; col <= cols; col++ ) {
    $col = $('<td>');
    $col.text(row + "|" + col);
    $col.attr('data-row', row);
    $col.attr('data-col', col);
    $row.append($col);
  }
  
  $table.append($row);
}
/* <<< */
var cells = [];

$('#myTable').click(function(e) {
  $cell = $(e.target);
  cells.unshift($cell);
  if(cells.length > 2) {
    cells.pop();
  }
  resetCells();
  markActiveCells();
  if ( cells.length == 2 ) {
    fillArea();
  }
});

function resetCells() {
  $('#myTable td').removeClass('active');
  $('#myTable td').removeClass('area');
}

function markActiveCells() {
  $(cells).each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
}

function fillArea() {
  if( cells.length < 2 ) return;
  
  start_row_cell = (cells[0].data('row') <= cells[1].data('row'))?0:1;
  start_col_cell = (cells[0].data('col') <= cells[1].data('col'))?0:1;
  
  start_row = cells[start_row_cell].data('row');
  end_row = cells[(start_row_cell+1)%2].data('row');
  
  start_col = cells[start_col_cell].data('col');
  end_col = cells[(start_col_cell+1)%2].data('col');

  for( let row = start_row; row <= end_row; row++ ) {
    for( let col = start_col; col <= end_col; col++ ) {
      $('#myTable td[data-row=' + row + '][data-col=' + col + ']').addClass('area');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  text-align: center;
}

td.active {
  background-color: #FA0 !important;
}

td.area {
  background-color: #FDA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" cellspacing=0></table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (I'm going through it). Do you think it's impossible/unreasonable to do it without using JQuery?

Comment: Can I ask you if there's a way of updating the DB (by using an external button, maybe) changing the records corresponding to the cells? Should I use Ajax?

Comment: @silcas Sure you can add a Button and use a funtion like `fillArea` to update the cells. - Yes you can use ajax for this.

Comment: @silcas you can do it without jQuery aswell, code would be a little bigget but no too big. try it :)